# get lan id expiration as a regular user not admin

Tags: powershell

```
import-module ActiveDirectory

(get-aduser "djohns02" -Properties AccountExpirationDate).AccountExpirationDate
```

This would work if the user had ADUC tools setup and configured on their machines. The problem is users will not have this setup and installed.

My next thought would be to try and setup a powershell script to run a remote script on a machine that does have this setup. Since they are not admins, they cannot get this setup and working as far as I know. As an admin I could force the trust and enable remote, but not as a standard user.

Are they any possibilities I am not thinking of? The goal is for contractors to be able to check when their account expires.

Answer (score 1):

```
net user %USERNAME% /domain
```

My program can filter the results and give me just the expiration

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PowerShell script you can use that does not require the AD cmdlets:

```
# Get-AccountExpirationDate.ps1
# Written by Bill Stewart

#requires -version 2

[CmdletBinding()]
param(
  [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [String[]] $Name
)

begin {
  $ACCOUNT_NEVER_EXPIRES = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

  $Searcher = [ADSISearcher] [ADSI] ""
  $Searcher.PageSize = 1000
  $Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange(@("accountexpires","distinguishedname","samaccountname"))

  function Get-SearchResultProperty {
    param(
      [System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyCollection] $properties,
      [String] $propertyName
    )
    if ( $properties[$propertyName] ) {
      $properties[$propertyName][0]
    }
  }

  function Get-AccountExpirationDate {
    param(
      $name
    )
    $Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(anr=$name))"
    $searchResults = $searcher.FindAll()
    $resultCount = ($searchResults | measure-object).Count
    if ( $resultcount -gt 0 ) {
      foreach ( $searchResult in $searchResults ) {
        $properties = $searchResult.Properties
        $accountExpires = Get-SearchResultProperty $properties "accountexpires"
        if ( $accountExpires -ne $null ) {
          if ( ($accountExpires -eq 0) -or ($accountExpires -eq $ACCOUNT_NEVER_EXPIRES) ) {
            $accountExpires = $null
          }
          else {
            $accountExpires = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($accountExpires)
          }
        }
        "" | select-object `
          @{Name = "distinguishedName"; Expression = {Get-SearchResultProperty $properties "distinguishedname"}},
          @{Name = "sAMAccountName";    Expression = {Get-SearchResultProperty $properties "samaccountname"}},
          @{Name = "accountExpires";    Expression = {$accountExpires}}
      }
    }
    $searchResults.Dispose()
  }
}

process {
  foreach ( $nameItem in $Name ) {
    Get-AccountExpirationDate $nameItem
  }
}
```

You can run it like this (assuming the script is in C:\Scripts):

```
PS C:\Scripts> .\Get-AccountExpirationDate.ps1 kendyer
```